# How to declare a GLOBAL variable an aspx website?

Tags: asp.net

How to declare a global variable or a public sub in a web application that all aspx pages can have access to?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544452/asp-net-lock-thread-method

That worked for me

Answer (score 2):

use a static variable in one of your code files.

Answer (score 1):

"Global" variables can be kept in Cache using `Cache.Add`, or Application state using `Application.Add`.

"Globally-available" methods are generally an antipattern and should be avoided.  If you need a utility function you can add a static method to a class, but beware the [Ball of Mud antipattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud).

Answer (score 0):

1.You can use session variables which will be available to all pages in the scope of current session.

C#
Session("name")=value;

2.You can use application variables which will be available to entire application code untill application ends.

Application("name") = value;

Answer (score 0):

Global.asax inherits from YourWebSiteApplicationClass...

```
public class YourWebSiteApplicationClass : HttpApplication
{
     public string GlobalVariable;
     public YourWebSiteApplicationClass()
     {
         GlobalVariable = "GLOBAL_VARIABLE";
     }
}
```

...and in any .aspx or .cs(.vb) file...

```
<% = ((YourWebSiteApplicationClass)this.ApplicationInstance).GlobalVariable %>
```

Return "GLOBAL_VARIABLE".

Comment: Please can you give me the VB version this class

Answer (score 0):

Create a PageBase class and have your pages inherit from it.